# "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" appears in a strange situation

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have two variables `a` (can be `undefined` or `Object`) and `b` (`Object`).

If `a.foo` exists, I want to set `b.foo` value. For this I wanted to use a single line expression, using `&&` operators.

Let's look at the example:

```
> a = {foo:'bar'}
{ foo: 'bar' }
> b = {}
{}
> c = {}
{}
> c.foo = a.foo // returns 'bar'
'bar'
> a && a.foo
'bar'
> a && a.foo && b.foo = a.foo // why doesn't this work?
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

I don't understand why `b.foo = a.foo` in this expression throws the error.

However, the following expressions work:

```
> a && a.foo && console.log("bar")
bar
undefined
> a && a.foo && (function () {return 'bar'})()
'bar'
> a && a.foo && (function () {b.foo = a.foo;})()
undefined
> b
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

Why? What's the explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of the expression

```
a && a.foo && b.foo
```

returns undefined, and you are saying

```
a && a.foo && b.foo = a.foo
```

so it is same as saying

```
undefined = a.foo
```

which is invalid

**You can assign a value to a variable, not a value.**

And in the following statement

```
a && a.foo && (function () {b.foo = a.foo;})()
```

you are saying if `a` & `a.foo` is truthy then you will execute the function. So here it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate the expression in `()`,

```
a && a.foo && (b.foo = a.foo)
```

Otherwise it will evaluate the comparison operations first before the assignment operations so it will evaluate as (order of precedence)

```
(a && a.foo && b.foo) = a.foo;
//or basically
true = a.foo //or false/undefined or whatever depending on what a,a.foo equal
```

If you take a look at the [order of precedence at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) you will see that the assignment operator is 17th (third from last) in the order, so it gets evaluated nearly after all other operations.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is we have to consider operator precedence in javascript.

Check here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

and operator (`&&`) has higher precedence over assignment (`=`) operator. So your all `&&` operation executes before the `=` operation. but you need `=` to be happening first. so putting parenthesis will solve the issue as it has higher precedence.

so the solution would be
`a && a.foo && (b.foo = a.foo)`